# SSRS Wildcard search in Report Parameters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

How do I write an SSRS Wildcard search in the Report Parameters

SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE Table1.Name = LIKE '%'@Name'%'

or

WHERE Table1.Name = in (:Name)?

How do I do this in SSRS?

Answer (score 4):

Say I have a very simple self-contained query in the report:

```
with val as
(
 select val = 'ABC'
 union all select 'DEF'
 union all select '1ABC3'
)
select *
from val
where val like @Param
```

I also have a parameter called `Param` in the report.

By default, even though I have `like` in the query, there are no wildcards so only exact matches will be returned:

[image]

If we look at the Dataset Properties, we can update the parameter being passed to add wildcards. By default it looks like this:

[image]

Change the Parameter Value expression to:

```
="%" & Parameters!Param.Value & "%"
```

Now the query text will be using a parameter with wildcards, so partial matches are returning data in the report:

[image]

**Alternative method**

Actually, thinking about this, perhaps an easier way to achieve the above is to do something like this in the report query text:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE Table1.Name = LIKE '%' + @Name + '%'
```

i.e. Just concatenate the wildcards directly to the parameter string. This works identically to the first option.

Comment: Hi Ian, Thanks for you help but I can't get it to work. The date between start and end works ok. However, when add the name para nothing returns. I've also used ="*" & Parameters!Paraname.Value & "*" .

Comment: Hmm, sorry about delayed response. Not sure why the first option didn't work - I've added an alternative.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this in the end?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it:

1. **Create a report parameter** (data type text) named MyFilter
2. **Create a DataSet** ReportData **with an expression for the source query**, something like:

> ="SELECT FilteredField, FieldValue FROM DataTable "  & IIF(Parameters!MyFilter.Value.ToString() = "",  "",  "WHERE
>   FilteredField LIKE '%" &
>   REPLACE(REPLACE(Parameters!MyFilter.Value.ToString(),"*","%"),"?","_")
>   & "%'")

As you can see, I have a basic SELECT statement which I concatenate with an empty string if the value for MyFilter is an empty string. If a value is filled in, I add a WHERE clause in which I replace the "*" by "%" and "?" by "_"

This is just a simplified version of what we actually did, allowing only "?" and "*" to be used as wildcards, but it works fine for our users.

Answer (score 0):

Use this will solve ur issue

="*" & Parametername.value & "*"